# c++ generic operator overload

Tags: c++, overloading

How could I use operator overloading to add two objects without making it a member of of any object? Is this something to do with insertion operator overloading?

so instead of this, to use something more generic i.e. to be used with any objects?:

```
sameObjectType operator + ( const sameObjectType  &x,  const sameObjectType &y ) {
    sameObjectType z;
    z = x+y;

    return z;
}

// I want to do the same for subtraction operatoR

sameObjectType operator - ( const sameObjectType  &x,  const sameObjectType &y ) {
    sameObjectType z;
    z = x-y;

    return z;
}
```

Comment: Note:  a wee problem with `z = x+y;` in your `operator +` overload. How do you think `x+y` is going to be calculated? Its going to call the operator overload you're smack-dab in the middle of already. i.e. your operator is infinitely recursive.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the idea from this sample code.**

```
#include <iostream>
class One {
private:
 int num1, num2;

public:
  One(int num1, int num2) : num1(num1), num2(num2) {}
  One& operator += (const One&);
  friend bool operator==(const One&, const One&);
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const One&);
};

std::ostream&
 operator<<(std::ostream& os, const One& rhs) {
   return os << "(" << rhs.num1 << "@" << rhs.num2 << ")";
 }

One& One::operator+=(const One& rhs) {
  num1 += rhs.num1;
  num2 += rhs.num2;
  return *this;
}

One operator+(One lhs, const One &rhs)
{
 return lhs+=rhs;
}

 int main () {
 One x(1,2), z(3,4);
 std::cout << x << " + " << z << " => " << (x+z) << "\n";
 }
```

Comment: I saw this code, the problem is that I am only initialising and calling Object reference. Object newObject;   newObject(1,2,3); cout << newObject + newObject;

Comment: One operator+(One lhs, const One &rhs)
{
 return lhs+=rhs;
}

see this there is not const with 1st parameter of function

Comment: it means the value of first object is not constant.

Comment: Can I create void type overload? for example, void operator+(One lhs, const One &rhs)

Comment: void add((One lhs, const One &rhs){
   lhs+=rhs;
}

Comment: if you got the required answer just place a tick of answer and also vote up my question. thanks

Comment: I will need to implement and check later if this is what I expected. The last thing I want to know if this would also work with different objects, say you got class with different constructor Two {long x; long y;} and you want to call from the main function like this Two foo ; cout << foo+foo+foo; to print a result of different type sum of objects. Will this work too?